# Pytorch DataLoader is not dividing the dataset into batches

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to load training data in the DataLoader with following code

```
class Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = torch.Tensor(self.x[index])
        y = torch.Tensor(self.y[index])
        return (x, y)

    def __len__(self):
        count = self.x.shape[0]
        return count
    
X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(-1,1,X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1]))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(-1,1,y_train.shape[0],y_train.shape[1]))
train_dataset = Dataset(X_train, y_train)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,batch_size=128,shuffle=True)
```

Now, when I check the length of the DataLoader, I get one dataset everytime. The loader is not splitting the dataset into batches. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems like your X_train includes an additional dimension, so Pytorch thinks that your dataset contains only a single sample. Did you try removing the -1 in your reshape? Maybe use -1 instead of 1

Comment: Tried with reshape(X_train,(-1,X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1])) but it's the same. Dataset is not being split.

Comment: Btw, how are you using the train_loader? `for batch in train_loader` and `print(batch.shape)`?

Comment: yes. but there is only one batch the dataset inside the dataloader.

Comment: any problem with the DataSet class may be?

Comment: What's the shape of `X_train`?

Comment: roughly 12000x1280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing your code, it seems to work perfectly if you remove the reshape steps. You're introducing a new dimension, so the new shape of X_train is (1, something, something), but you're indexing your items using `self.x[index]`, so you're always accessing the batch dimension. You make the same mistake when calculating the length of your dataset: is always 1.

Solution: do not reshape.

```py
X_train = np.random.rand(12_000, 1280)
y_train = np.random.rand(12_000, 1)
train_dataset = Dataset(X_train, y_train)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,batch_size=128,shuffle=True)

for x, y in train_loader:
    print(x.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    break
```

Comment: superb! thanks for pointing that out. the dataloader was considering 1 as the dataset length.